# What does graph of a function mean?

Tags: velocity, speed

I'm asked to do a graph for the speed of the rocket as a function of the flight altitude.
Here are the values: h (m) 0 4 13 32 55 83 103 and v (m/s) 0 4 7 12 16 20 23. Does this mean that the flight altitude should be on the x-axis?

Comment: "... as a function of $x$" typically means that $x$ should be on the horizontal axis. The function itself is then up the vertical axis.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asked to graph as a function of altitude, then yes, your flight altitude should be your independent variable in the function, i.e. $v(h)$

Comment: Why v(h) can't I write f(h)?

Comment: So basically function of something means that it should be on the x-axis?

Comment: You can certainly write $f(h)$. It's just that $v(h)$ is a more intuitive name to your velocity function. i.e. calling your velocity function $f(h)$ isn't as intuitive as $v(h)$. In the end it's just personal preference.